# AHK fails to execute when the "trigger" is used in the window that is in scope. Is there a way to make AHK "greedier"?

Tags: windows, automation, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I'm trying to switch between virtual desktops on win10 using the `XButton1` and `XButton2` of my mouse.

So far this is working quite alright, except the fact that when I have for example Firefox as my active scope, obviously those buttons are used to go forward/backward (problem appears in every window using these buttons for something).

This seems to prevent AHK from either noticing that I used the configured trigger or not executing the script (which I believe is less likely).

For Firefox I found a workaround by disabling the use of these buttons in the [about: config](about config) page by setting `mousbutton.4th.enable` and `mouse button.5th.enable` to `false` but this won't work for everything since there isn't always a way to disable these buttons.

I have tried to use the mouse-wheel tilting buttons as well but the default usage oh them is even more common in the programs I'm working with.

Here is the script I am using.

```
# NoEnv; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
SendMode Input; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

XButton1::Send ^#{Left}
XButton2::Send ^#{Right}

return
```

If someone has a workaround or a completely different idea (for example   a totally obvious Win10 feature/setting I'm missing) I would be absolutely happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define custom combinations for those two keys in your script
e.g.

```
XButton1 & LButton::return ; do nothing
; or another action:
; XButton1 & LButton:: Run notepad
XButton1::Send ^#{Left}

XButton2 & a::return 
XButton2::Send ^#{Right}
```

This way the keys lose their native function in the programs.

For details, see [Custom Combinations](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#combo).

**EDIT:**

If a program is running with admin privileges, then AHK won't intercept the key presses, and that could very well be the reason behind this problem.

If that is the case,  try to run the AHK script as administrator by adding this to the [auto-execute section](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto) (top of the script):

```
; If the script is not elevated, relaunch as administrator and kill current instance:

full_command_line := DllCall("GetCommandLine", "str")

if not (A_IsAdmin or RegExMatch(full_command_line, " /restart(?!\S)"))
{
    try ; leads to having the script re-launching itself as administrator
    {
        if A_IsCompiled
            Run *RunAs "%A_ScriptFullPath%" /restart
        else
            Run *RunAs "%A_AhkPath%" /restart "%A_ScriptFullPath%"
    }
    ExitApp
}
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm#RunAs.

Comment: Unfortunately even though this makes totaly sense and is described exactly like that in the documentation as you stated with your link it does not work.

Comment: Try to run the script as administrator as in the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

When in need to use AHK the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57389131/8152637) from user3419297 works perfekt.

Another way to accomplish the same result is to use [X-Mouse Button Control](https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/xmousebuttoncontrol.htm).

Simply set Mouse Button 4/5 to `Simulated Keys:` with `{CTRL}{LWIN}{RIGHT}` and `{CTRL}{LWIN}{LEFT}`.